# Class of functional equations that backpropagation can solve

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation

There is a theorem that states that basically a neural network can approximate any function whatsoever. However, this does not mean that it can solve any equation. I have some notes where it states that backpropagation allows us to solve problems of the following kind

$$ F(x_i, t) = y_i $$

Can someone point me to what exactly this means?